# Java HTTP servlet to echo data from POST

Tags: java, sockets, http, servlets

I am trying to write a simple java socket that will take an HTTP POST request

Right now I have this socket code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/listener", new MyHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
    }

    static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            String response = "This is the response";
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }

}
```

I want to send it "Some simple string" through a post and have it write that string to a file.

What is the best method to do this?

Comment: Do not try to reinvent the wheel. Use the already made in class `URLConnection` or third party library like Apache HttpClient.

Comment: For your application do you have to use the `com.sun.net.httpserver` package? Or can you create a socket server instead? Creating socket servers is fairly straight forward.

Comment: This is NOT a servlet nor does it have *anything* to do with servlets, so take the `servlets` tag out. Even if you get your little http server functioning fairly well, it will still not be a servlet container.  If you want servlets, just install Tomcat already.